# Fast character replacement table for strings?

Tags: string, characters, mapping

Does Emacs have an API for creating a character translation table which can then be efficiently applied to strings?

A data structure for example that can be created using a set of source & destination characters.

Python has a function that does this for example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans

---

I would like to use this in a performance critical code-path, where regex replacement isn't so practical.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are [translation tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-of-Characters.html) (that's node *Translation Tables* of the Elisp manual).

These are
[char-tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTables.html) whose elements are characters. A char-table is a table indexed by chars. (A char-table can have elements of any type.)

You can make a translation table from a list of translation pairs `(FROM . TO)` with function `make-translation-table`. Or you can make one from a vector (`make-translation-table-from-vector`) or an alist (`make-translation-table-from-alist`).

(The alist has `(FROM . TO)` elements, but each `FROM` can be a character or a vector of characters, and the resulting translation table also includes a reverse translation.)

---

As a general utility to act on the elements of a char-table you have function `map-char-table`:

> `map-char-table` is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(map-char-table FUNCTION CHAR-TABLE)`
> ?
> Call `FUNCTION` for each character in `CHAR-TABLE` that has non-`nil` value.
>
> `FUNCTION` is called with two arguments, `KEY` and `VALUE`.
>
> `KEY` is a character code or a cons of character codes specifying a
> range of characters that have the same value.
>
> `VALUE` is what `(char-table-range CHAR-TABLE KEY)` returns.

Comment: This answer misses a method to apply the translation table to a string. There is `translate-region` which is close but requires a region in a buffer.

Comment: You didn't ask for such a method. You asked *"Does Emacs have an API for creating a character translation table which can then be efficiently applied to strings?"* I pointed you to an API for creating such a table. You can then write a function to apply its translation to a string.

Comment: Character level operations in elisp are unlikely to be very efficient. In that case I'd likely write a version of `translate-region` in C that applies to strings instead.

Comment: Checking further, it looks like there is a C function to perform this operation decode-coding-string / encode-coding-string, although this requires a coding system (defined by define-coding-system which can take a translation table as an argument).